# rm($filename) method in Varien_Io_Sftp does not delete remote file

Tags: cron, varien, ftp

I'm pretty new to Magento dev so forgive me if some of my terminology isn't quite right.

My module needs to download and delete XML files from a remote FTP server using the sftp protocol. I'm using the Varien_Io_Sftp class to do that.

I'm able to open the connection, change to the needed directory and retrieve the file but when I try to delete it using the Varien_Io_Sftp rm method the remote file is not deleted.

```
<?php
    $vcXMLOut   = "/XML/export";
    $filename   = "test.txt"
    $sftpGetFiles = new Varien_Io_Sftp();
    $sftpGetFiles->open(
        array(
            'host'  => "ftp.test.com",
            'username'  => "test",
            'password'  => "test",
            'timeout'   => '100'
        )
    );
    $sftpGetFiles->cd($vcXMLOut);
    $file = $sftpGetFiles->read($filename); //Contents of file are read successfully
    $sftpGetFiles->rm($filename);   //File remains
```

I've ruled out permissions problems on the file.

I'm not sure why I'm not getting any errors anywhere. Is it because this code is being run in a cron schedule? The database says the scheduled jobs were successful. Nothing that I can find in any logs.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Anyone have any ideas how I could better debug this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some poking around it looks like that while the read method accepts a filename relative to the current directory, the rm method needs the path included. The following code works for me.

```
<?php
    $vcXMLOut   = "/XML/export";
    $filename   = "test.txt"
    $sftpGetFiles = new Varien_Io_Sftp();
    $sftpGetFiles->open(
        array(
            'host'  => "ftp.test.com",
            'username'  => "test",
            'password'  => "test",
            'timeout'   => '100'
        )
    );
    $sftpGetFiles->cd($vcXMLOut);
    $file = $sftpGetFiles->read($filename); //Contents of file are read successfully
    $sftpGetFiles->rm($sftpGetFiles->pwd().$filename);   //File is successfully deleted
```

Comment: I'm still interested in learning ways I could have better debugged this and I'm positive that someone could give a more complete answer than I could. Please feel free to add other answers!